# Alternative to shared_from_this in destructor

Tags: c++11, weak-ptr

```
class A
{
   std::set<std::weak_ptr<B>, std::owner_less<std::weak_ptr<B>>> m_coll;
public:
   remove(const std::weak_ptr<B> &refWptrB);
}

class B : public std::enable_shared_from_this<B>
{
   ~B() { sharedPtrOfA->remove(shared_from_this()); }
}
```

Although I cannot use `shared_from_this()` in the dtor, this seems like a valid use case as in `A::remove()` i'm not concerned about the stored pointer's memory, just the reference-count-block location on which i suppose `std::owner_less` and `std::owner_before` work.

I can think of alternatives:

(a) use delayed purging (eg., when iterating over `A::m_coll` later if you find that shared_ptr obtained by locking is null/false then remove the weak_ptr from the collection).

(b)store a weak_ptr in `B` itself { ofcourse obtained via shared_from_this() } and pass that to `A::remove(..)` in dtor of `B`.

But is there any solution that is made possible through a known idiom (for instance if it were required by the standard to store the weak_ptr in `std::enable_shared_from_this` then I could access this in the dtor of `B` and get the job done) ?

{Btw I can't use (a) above as i need to trigger lot of things immediately when a `B` in `A::m_coll` is destroyed.}

Comment: What is `std::order_{less,before}`?

Comment: :) owner ofcourse - editing it.

Comment: You could also try to use raw pointers to order the members in `m_coll`. Though raw pointer comparison using `<` is often unspecified (for pointers not in the same array), for most implementations it is well-behaved. A `std::unordered_map` or `unordered_set` is also possible, `hash<T*>` has defined behaviour. Other than that, I think b) sounds reasonable.

Comment: Little worried about using raw pointers. What if a thread reaches the dtor of `B` while the other's iterating over `A::m_coll` in A?

Comment: @ustulation That's not even thread-safe when using weak pointers! One thread that reads from `m_coll` and one that modifies it, leads to a race condition (no matter what the `value_type` is).

Comment: @dyp No that's not what i meant. m_coll is protected from simultaneous reads and writes, but it's difficult to do that for the raw pointer inside weak_ptr inside m_coll. Eg., say you had m_coll as collection of raw B*. Now while iterating you would do m_coll.at(x)->someFuncInB(); But just before that B* held by m_coll.at(x) gets destroyed in some other thread and code reaches the dtor of B. Just then there is context-switching and m_coll.at(x)->someFuncInB(); is executed.

Comment: @dyp: Contd... Now I don't want someFuncInB() to execute when another thread has already reached the dtor of B (it's bad programming anyway - that function could be doing some async operations and would need further care etc.). With weak_ptrs you would lock and check and won't have such problems.

Comment: Ah ok. Note I said you can use raw pointer to *order* the members. For example, you can use an `unordered_map<B*, weak_ptr<B>>` and store the `weak_ptr` not in the instance of `B`, but in the map.